# RecyclerView не показывает тень на границах

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть макет:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="-19dp"
    android:paddingRight="-19dp">

    <io.supercharge.shimmerlayout.ShimmerLayout
        android:id="@+id/animationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:shimmer_animation_duration="1500"
        app:shimmer_auto_start="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:overScrollMode="always"/>

    </io.supercharge.shimmerlayout.ShimmerLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

При скроллинге перестало показывать тень когда достигаем края данных. Не могу понять в чем причина. Если кто-то сталкивался то не подскажите как вы справились этой проблемой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло добавть `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`
Внутри содержались элементы требующие этого флага.